# Creating a background image in Jumbotron

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to create a background image in a jumbotron bootstrap template but it is not being displayed. The code that I am writing in CSS is:

html:

```
<div class="jumbotron"> 
      <div class="container">
        <p>The RobFran Restaurant opened its doors in May 2010. During this short time, this restaurant has built an 
           excellent reputation for its food, services and location...</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="about.php" role="button">Read more &raquo;</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Css:

```
.jumbotron {
    background-image: url("view.jpg");
}
```

What am I doing wrong please?
Thanks!

Comment: Try adding `!important` before the semicolon, ie: `background: url("view.jpg") !important;`

Answer (score 1):

check to make sure you path to the file(view.jpg) is correct.

change your stylesheet to

```
.jumbotron{
   background: url('view.jpg');
}
```

Comment: my path is correct. I have just copied the code in html where I want to create the background image. Can you please check if there is something wrong? Thanks

Comment: ok in your style sheet instead of background-image: url (),  put background: url( ).

Comment: If that doesnt help, where in the file tree is your 'view.jpg' in accordance to the index.html file?